# What are expl3 equivalents for various macros useful to debugging and a building private packages

Tags: expl3

When I'm writing my own private style packages, such as when developing them, I find it useful to use `\typeout` to help me see what I've currently created or figure out what line of code is the source of the issues (particularly when a mysterious error message is getting thrown).

Currently, I'm refractoring some old `expl3` code I created back when I  understood very little `expl3`.  Throughout that code I've got things like `\typeout` and a judicious sprinkling of `\space` thrown in there to make terminal output simple and easy to read.  I've come to actually like this terminal output because it helps me debug things, but I can't find anything `expl3` equivalents of `\typeout`.  The best I can find is `\msg_warning:...` which throws too much to the terminal.

Similarly, I like that I can concatenate `\space` to create larger white space on the terminal screen.  Concatenating `~` doesn't work.

A third macro I've come to really appreciate when debugging and outputting to terminal is `\detokenize`.

It would seem that when write `expl3`, I should stick with `expl3` macros and such.  Does anyone have any suggestions about writing `expl3` equivalents for:

```
\typeout{....}
\detokenize{....}
\space
```

Comment: `\msg_term:n` should be what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `\iow_term:n` that expands macros in the usual way.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_term:n {Hi,~Andrew,~how~are~you?~This~message~will~automatically~
 wrap~when~reaching~a~predefined\c_space_tl limit. \\ \\
 You~can~force~a~break~and~use~\exp_not:N \tl_to_str:n
 for~showing~\tl_to_str:n{\whatever~you~\want}}
```

This will output

```
*************************************************
* Hi, Andrew, how are you? This message will automatically wrap when
* reaching a predefined limit.
* 
* You can force a break and use \tl_to_str:n for showing \whatever you \want 
*************************************************
```

So `\iow_term:n` is the analog of `\typeout`, while `\tl_to_str:n` is `\detokenize`; a space is `\c_space_tl`, which is *exactly* the same as `\space`.

There's also `\iow_log:n` for writing to the log file only.

Comment: Backslash-space is an alternative to `~` within any text that is wrapped, and can be useful when wanting to produce several spaces in a row.

Comment: @egreg: You could update your response using  `\iow_term`

Comment: @egreg Just as a comment, the current output does not look like your example (at least not in my current distribution).

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Yes, the format for messages has been changed since.

Comment: @egreg How can I get a nice message like the one in your example?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL You need to define your own message system.

Comment: @egreg OK :-), `\iow_wrap:nnnN`?

Answer (score 5):

`grep` is your friend:

```
l3kernel/l3tl.dtx:\cs_new_eq:NN \tl_to_str:n \etex_detokenize:D


l3kernel/l3tl.dtx:\tl_const:Nn \c_space_tl { ~ }
```

for messages if you don't like the `\msg` functions, probably `\typeout` is still your friend.

Comment: `\c_space_tl` doesn't get expanded within a `\msg_` command.  (I'll try to put together a simple example of what I mean).  Also, after a bit of digging, I found `\iow_term:x` which seems to do what `\terminal` does:  am I right?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\c_space_char` might be more to your liking

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\c_space_token`? `\c_space_tl` doesn't get expanded because it's a token list so it's `\unexpanded{ }`?

Comment: @Manuel see the OP is spoilt for choice:-)

Comment: I would go for `\space` even in expl3 code.

Comment: @Manuel sure but where's the fun in that

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is no longer accurate, no more stars and the expansion policy has changed. One must adapt to use either `\iow_term:n` or `\iow_term:x`, the former expands nothing while the latter expands... what is expandable.

Here is an example with various settings to illustrate how to expand some macros, or not.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { 2 + 2 }
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \l_tmpa_tl }
\iow_term:n{****~\iow_term:n :~\l_tmpa_tl~=~\l_tmpa_int}
\iow_term:x{****~\iow_term:x :~\l_tmpa_tl~\c_space_tl=~\l_tmpa_int}
\iow_term:x{****~\iow_term:x :~\l_tmpa_tl~\c_space_tl=~\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int}
\iow_term:x{****~\iow_term:x :~\exp_not:N \l_tmpa_tl~=~\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The terminal output reads

```
**** \iow_term:n : \l_tmpa_tl = \l_tmpa_int 
**** \iow_term:x : 2+2 = \l_tmpa_int 
**** \iow_term:x : 2+2 = 4
**** \iow_term:x : \l_tmpa_tl = 4
```

The `\c_space_tl` was sometimes necessary to insert a space before the `=`.